# Tensorflow last layer gives `TypeError`

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I run the code below, I get "TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Received: layer=1 of type <class 'int'>" error

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sbn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

dataFrame = pd.read_excel("merc.xlsx")

yuzdeDoksanDokuzDf = dataFrame.sort_values("price",ascending = False).iloc[131:]
dataFrame = yuzdeDoksanDokuzDf
dataFrame = dataFrame[dataFrame.year != 1970]
dataFrame = dataFrame.drop("transmission",axis=1)

y= dataFrame["price"].values
x= dataFrame.drop("price",axis=1).values

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=10)

scaler =MinMaxScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler.fit_transform(x_test)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(12,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(12,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(12,activation="relu")) 
model.add(1)

model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="mse")

model.fit(x=x_train, y = y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),batch_size=250,epochs=300)
```

I am still in the learning phase, I want it to work as in the training video I watched, I wrote the codes without errors, but it does not work

Comment: The problem is because you are adding a layer `model.add(1)` with value `1` which is not meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the line causing the problem is:

```
model.add(1)
```

Here is how you can correct that line:

```
model.add(Dense(1))
```

Comment: it works then vote :)